# operator does not exist: integer = bigint[]

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

When using a custom SQL query with Prisma, I keep getting the following error when trying to pass an array of numbers to the IN parameter. Converting it to a string of comma seperate values also doesn't work.

The home_tryscorer_ids = [1,2,7]

Here is my query. Does anyone know how to correctly pass in the home_tryscorer_ds as 1,2,7.

```
const numberOfTryscorers: number = home_tryscorer_ids.length;

const games: GameType[] = await this.db
  .$queryRaw`
    SELECT g.*, COUNT(DISTINCT p."player_id")
    FROM "public"."NrlPlayerToGame" p
    JOIN "public"."NrlGame" g ON p."game_id" = g."id"
    WHERE p."player_id" IN (${home_tryscorer_ids}) AND "tries" >= 1
    GROUP BY g."id", g."date", g."home_team_id", g."away_team_id"
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p."player_id") = ${numberOfTryscorers}
  `;
```

Comment: Many drivers do not understand array types. Try dynamically building the query by converting to a csv and concatenating as a string. Do guard against SQL injection though.

Comment: An array may "look like" the comma separated list needed by IN, but those commas don't actually exist in the array elements. So you need to work with a string that does have the commas in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `home_tryscorer_ids` is an array: [`IN ()` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR) doesn't support them but [`=ANY()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) does: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-wHCF2xt)

```sql
const numberOfTryscorers: number = home_tryscorer_ids.length;

const games: GameType[] = await this.db
  .$queryRaw`
    SELECT g.*, COUNT(DISTINCT p."player_id")
    FROM "public"."NrlPlayerToGame" p
    JOIN "public"."NrlGame" g ON p."game_id" = g."id"
    WHERE p."player_id"=ANY(${home_tryscorer_ids}) AND "tries" >= 1
    GROUP BY g."id", g."date", g."home_team_id", g."away_team_id"
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p."player_id") = ${numberOfTryscorers}
  `;
```

Same can be done with [`array_position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.8.1.1.1) that returns a `NULL` if the element is not in the array:

```sql
WHERE ARRAY_POSITION(${home_tryscorer_ids}, p."player_id") IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The IN operator in SQL expects a comma-separated list of values, but home_tryscorer_ids is an array of numbers (esp. no commas!). A way to get around this is to convert the array to a string of comma-separated values using the join() method before passing it to the query.

This should work:

```
const home_tryscorer_ids = [1, 2, 7];
const numberOfTryscorers = home_tryscorer_ids.length;
const home_tryscorer_ids_string = home_tryscorer_ids.join(',');

const games: GameType[] = await this.db.$queryRaw`
  SELECT g.*, COUNT(DISTINCT p."player_id")
  FROM "public"."NrlPlayerToGame" p
  JOIN "public"."NrlGame" g ON p."game_id" = g."id"
  WHERE p."player_id" IN (${home_tryscorer_ids_string})
    AND "tries" >= 1
  GROUP BY g."id", g."date", g."home_team_id", g."away_team_id"
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p."player_id") = ${numberOfTryscorers}
`;
```

Note that this assumes that the values in home_tryscorer_ids are safe to use directly in the SQL query. If the values come from user input, it's important to sanitize that to prevent SQL injection attacks.